# Issue installing rDEA - compilation failed for package

Tags: r, compiler-errors, install.packages

I'm trying to use the package rDEA. I have most recent r version 3.4.4 ("Someone to Lean On"). I'm using most recent R Studio 1.1.423.

I get the error **compilation failed for package 'rDEA'**. Can anyone help?

**Precise details:**

> install.packages("rDEA")

```
Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘rDEA’
    Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
    y/n:
```

I type **y**, and get the following:

```
installing the source package ‘rDEA’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rDEA_1.2-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 57007 bytes (55 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 55 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rDEA’ ...
** package ‘rDEA’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: GLPK: No such file or directory
make: *** [GLPK.ts] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rDEA’
* removing 
‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rDEA’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rDEA’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
```

‘/private/var/folders/b1/_pstgqks0r3gb3t972tk8zh00000gn/T/RtmpuvqGid/downloaded_packages’

Comment: you need to install the GLPK library. Given the paths in the ouput, I believe your on MacOS, so you need to install the glpk package from homebrew (https://brew.sh/).

Comment: What OS are you running? Have you tryed installing the GLPK package before this one?

Comment: @xraynaud Thank you. I've just successfully installed homebrew. How do I call it in r? I tried install.packages("glpk") but it says it's unavailable for r version 3.4.4

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier Thank you. I'm on MacOS, X El Capitan 10.11.6. I've tried installing glpk but it says it's unavailable for r version 3.4.4. If I try rGLPK I get the same compilation error as with my attempt to install rDEA.

Comment: @JessicaMilligan: no, the glpk libs are not a R package. You need to `brew install glpk` from a Mac Terminal.

Comment: Right - I see! I installed homebrew via the terminal, then brew install glpk via the terminal, then install.package("rDEA") in r. It works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: My computer system is windows, if you install this package from source files, just download glpk.h from GitHub, and put it in src. But when compile it, this package has the other problem,I have issued on their page.